# Show there exists a subsequence that converges weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence

In PDE by Evans, Chapter 8.4.2. we want to minimize the energy functional

$$ I[w]: = \int \frac{1}{2} |Dw|^2 - fw dx $$

among all functions in $$ A: = \{ w \in H^1_0(U): w \geq h \; \;  a.e. \}$$

with $h: \overline{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

To prove the existence of a minimizer, we let $\{u_k \}$ be such that $I[u_k] \rightarrow  m = \inf_w I[w]$.

We want to show there exists a subsequence $u_{k_j} \rightharpoonup u$ converging weakly in $H^1_0(U)$ so that by compactness $u_{k_j} \rightarrow u$ strongly in $L^2(U)$.

My question is how do we show that such a subsequence exists? i.e. how do we find a weakly converging subsequence?

I understand that if we can show that $\{ u_k \}$ is bounded in $H^1_0(U)$ then we can use reflexivity to get a weakly convergent subseq, but how to bound $\|u_k\|_{L^2(U)}$?

Also, bounding $\|Du_k \|_{L^2(U)}$ is enough, because then we can apply poincare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if I am missing something. However, I think it is just this.

\begin{align} 
I(u) & = \int \frac{1}{2}| Du |^2 - \int f u \\
& \geq \frac{1}{2}\| Du\|^2 - \| f\| \|u \| & \text{Holder}\\
& \geq \frac{1}{2}\| Du\|^2 - C\|f \| \| Du \| & \text{Poincare}
\end{align}

Thus, if we take a minimizing sequence $u_n$, then $I(u_n)$ can be taken to be a bounded sequence. Then, the bound on $I(u_n)$ should allow you to bound $\|Du\|$.

Comment: I was also thinking something like this,and maybe using some Cauchy inequality, but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: If $\| Du_n\|^2 - K \| Du_n\|$ is a sequence of real numbers bounded from above then $\|D_n\|$ must be a bounded sequence of real numbers. I’m looking at the graph of $x^2 - Kx$. The bound on  $\| Du_n\|^2 - K \| Du_n\|$ comes from the fact that it is bounded above by the energy of $u_n$ which is converging to the inf.